# How to display the content of a database into a QListWidget

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I am wondering how to display the title and the ID form a data base into a QListWidget. The ID will not be visible but when the item is clicked it has to be able to use that ID to search the database for more information.

{I'm using c++ in Qt and SQLite3 for the database.}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using QListWidget it is recommended to use QListView with QSqlTableModel where you can use the setModelColumn method to indicate the column "title" that you want to show and use QSqlRecord to access the "id":

```cpp
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtWidgets>

static bool createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, QObject::tr("Cannot open database"),
            QObject::tr("Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                        "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                        "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                        "to build it.\n\n"
                        "Click Cancel to exit."), QMessageBox::Cancel);
        return false;
    }
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("CREATE TABLE mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title VARCHAR(20))");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO mytable(title) VALUES('Title1')");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO mytable(title) VALUES('Title2')");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO mytable(title) VALUES('Title3')");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO mytable(title) VALUES('Title4')");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO mytable(title) VALUES('Title5')");
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    if(!createConnection())
        return -1;
    QSqlTableModel model;
    model.setTable("mytable");
    model.select();
    QListView view;
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.setModelColumn(model.record().indexOf("title"));

    QObject::connect(&view, &QAbstractItemView::clicked, [&model](const QModelIndex & index){
        QSqlRecord rec = model.record(index.row());
        qDebug() << rec.value("id").toInt();
    });
    view.resize(640, 480);
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```